# How do I create tables for the following schema ?

Tags: sql, database

I'm a beginner and am having trouble with respect to the relations. Here I have two tables with `1:infinity relation`. I'd appreciate it if someone helps me understand how to create the tables for them.

```
A has id, name attribute
B has id , email password attribute

A:B = 1:infinity.
```

How to create this?

Also **if A has infinity relation** on itself , how will that work out ?

Comment: Please add some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name VARCHAR(64),
  user_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_users_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);

CREATE TABLE accounts
(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  user_id INT NOT NULL, 
  email VARCHAR(64), 
  password VARCHAR(32),
  CONSTRAINT fk_accounts_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5a223/1)** demo